# In gtsummary, is there a way to change the text used for a value (the category value, not the label for the category)?

Tags: gtsummary

I am using the excellent gtsummary R package.
As an example, my gtsummary table has columns for multiple characteristics of people in a clinical trial and a column for treatment A and treatment B.

For each group I have various characteristics such as gender. In my dataframe gender is listed as "m" or "f" and I want the table to list these as "Male" and "Female".
I know how to change labels e.g label = list( gender ~ "Gender"), but how do I change the values?

(I know I can go into the dataframe and change them there, but can I do this in gtsummary)

Comment: You'll want to make the changes on the data frame before passing it to tbl_summary. The first argument of tbl_summary is the data frame, so you can make changes to a data frame and pipe directly to the summary function

Comment: Ok, I'll do that, thank you for responding so promptly.